# Excel is not starting using win32 on Django application running on Apache

Tags: python, django, excel, apache, winapi

I have an application build on Django 2.1.4. I have a piece of code which converts excel xlsx to PDF using win32 COM object. The problem is the same code works on a QA environment which has the same specification as PROD.

Below code is not initiating the excel application because of which I'm not able to convert this workbook to PDF. It is returning an Excel Application but excel does not start. I have kept "`xlApp.Visible = True`"..

```
xlApp = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
```

The above code works fine with IDLE environment and converts excel to PDF whereas inside Django's view function it has a problem.

I'm also using pythoncom.CoInitialize() inside View function.

Tried running it on IDLE and it works fine.. It has a problem inside Django application

print("PDF Required")

```
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
xlApp = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
#xlApp = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
print("xlApp : ",xlApp)
xlApp.Visible = False
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(os.getcwd() + '\\' + directory_name + '\\' + 
directory_name + '.xlsx')
print("Books : ",books)
#ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws = books.Worksheets('CFS')
ws.Visible = 1
print("Visible is 1")
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, os.getcwd() + '\\' + directory_name + '\\' + 
directory_name + '.pdf')
print("Exported ")
xlApp.Quit()
```

The expected output is a PDF with the same name as xlsx file in the same directory

Comment: If this code runs in a service, then it is doomed to fail. Services run inside session 0, a non-visual session, and Excel is not happy there.

Comment: But the same code is working on a QA environment where Excel to PDF conversion is happening on a Django Application running on Apache. .. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Is the code running in a service? Also, if code fails, debug it. You can't succeed as a programmer blind, you need to debug.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you please elaborate on your first comment. I'm still a newbie and learning to debug.. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Debugging your comment actually helped :D Thank you! Works fine now.